# Shrink volume past 3258MB

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I am wondering how I can shrink my C: volume past 3258MB as I have a 1.79TB Harddrive with 1.57TB free, and I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files](http://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files), [Can't shrink to available partition volume in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/781985/cant-shrink-to-available-partition-volume-in-windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That does not help one bit, so I would appreciate it if you could remove that please.

Comment: You asked how to shrink the partition past a certain size.  This is a common problem/question about Windows (as shown by those two possible duplicates). How do they not help? Perhaps edit your question to include what you've tried already, and where exactly you're getting tripped up.

Answer (score 0):

There is many tools for that like disk management :start menu =>right click on computer => manage 
You can also try a demo and desinstall it right after 
I recently use 
[http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/resize-partition-windows-7.htm]
whith success: i needed to remove space from my linux partiton (because of farcry 4)

Comment: So that will allow me to create a new partition which will allow me to install Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Doesn't work, I would appreciate it if you gave me a link to something that was useful and not like $60

Comment: i'd mentioned that  _You can also try a demo and desinstall it right after _ sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: It wouldn't let me partition my hard drive without buying it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking **how** to shrink your C drive, then you can use **Disk Management.**

1. Open **Disk Management**.

[image]

2. Right-click on **(C:)** under `Volume`, choose **Shrink Volume**.
3. Enter the desired size you want to shrink from C: (in MB, 1GB=1024MB).
4. You should then see a "block" of **Unallocated Space** of the size you chose (in black) appear underneath.

**Note 1:** If an error pops up saying Windows cannot shrink past x MB, then refer to Techie's answer.

**Note 2**: Doesn't Ubuntu require a [minimum of 5GB of space?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Comment: It **requires** 5GB, I can only shrink to around 3.44GB

Comment: How do you know you can only shrink it to 3.44 GB?

Comment: It comes up with it.

Comment: Then refer to Techie's link. You should have stated that you were unable to shrink past 3.44GB in your question.

Comment: I believe I did? _how I can shrink my C: volume past 3258MB_

Comment: You didn't state that you were *unable* to shrink it past 3GB but *how* to shrink it past 3GB. Then when Techie pointed you in the right direction you said that it didn't help one bit.

Comment: _I am wondering how I can shrink my C: volume past 3258MB_  3258MB = ~3.3GB

Comment: Then why did you say that it didnt help one bit then? (And 3258MB=~3.2GB to be nitpicky)